# Python not finding a library (so, dll) from a PyPi package

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 library and trying to use pylupdate:

`from PyQt5.pylupdate_main import main`

This gives me the error:

> ImportError: libQt5Xml.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

While the file is located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/`

I could fix by doing:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH python -c "from PyQt5.pylupdate_main import main"`

It used to work without adding the path before.
How can this be done? Is this something to fix in the wheel?

---

This can be easily reproduced with Docker:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install PyQt5
RUN echo $(ls /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5)
RUN ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5
RUN python -c "from PyQt5.pylupdate_main import main"
```

---

Output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5` is these:

```
 ---> Running in 6c4c1fbe5de2
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffecb7d5000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fbc76abe000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbc76a94000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbc76910000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbc7678d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbc76773000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbc765b2000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbc76392000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007fbc75ef9000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007fbc75b41000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007fbc7415e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbc74159000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbc74154000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbc74033000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbc774d1000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fbc73fbf000)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @KlausD. question added ;)

Comment: You say it used to work. Can you think of anything you might have done in the meantime that could have possibly changed it? Did you move anything? Reinstall anything?..?

Comment: what is the output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5`

Comment: @Iguananaut I changed nothing, this running on Travis CI, and it started to fail. The only source of changes could be in the wheel itself (no reply from the mailing list) or in Travis.

Comment: @eyllanesc question updated with the ldd output

Comment: @DenisRouzaud you could share the .travis.yml and the other files necessary to reproduce the problem and then be able to give a clearer solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc I added a minimum Dockerfile to reproduce

Comment: @DenisRouzaud The problem is that PyQt5 did not think you should import that module, so the project structure did not take that case into account. The cause of the problem is pylupdate.abi3.so you cannot find the .so of Qt since these are not in a standard path.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks a lot, that seems indeed to be the right pointer. pylupdate.abi3.so is pointing to the system libraries (incompatible) while QtCore.abi3.so is pointing the site-packages library. Cheers!

Comment: the new version of the package (5.14.1) actually fixes this

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in the current version of PyQt5 on pypi (5.14.0) that doesn't set some links or paths correctly.

<strike>You can fix this by manually installing `libqt5xml5`, for example by modifying your `Dockerfile` like this</strike>

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install PyQt5
RUN apt update && apt install -y libqt5xml5
RUN python -c "from PyQt5.pylupdate_main import main"
```

As a workaround, you can use the previous version (5.13.2) that seems not to have this problem.

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install -I PyQt5==5.13.2
RUN python -c "from PyQt5.pylupdate_main import main"
```

Comment: mmm, The difference between installing using apt-get and pip is that the first one uses the Qt libraries of the system, and in the second one it uses a Qt provided by pypi. So you will always find the .so since they are on the official routes that posix handles but in the case of pip they are on different paths.

Comment: In your case the patch works because probably the libQt5Xml.so installed through the libqt5xml5 package has not changed with respect to Qt 5.14 since the QtXML module has not had great changes luckily, but that may fail.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc for the clarification. I'll change the answer and leave only the second workaround...